# Apply pre_get_posts filter in a certain moment (just for a particular block of posts)

Tags: filters, pre-get-posts

I want to apply a filter to a block of posts, for a custom field that I created, called: 'highlighted_in'. To filter the results I'm using the 'pre_get_posts' hook, and **it works**.

But I think my approach is very precarious. I had to do test and error with a var counter `$_REQUEST["BQ_EXEC"]` increase it until I get the value of the correct moment when performs the query that feeds the block of posts, in which I want to apply the filter.

This is the code, that I put in functions.php:

```
function my_post_filter($query) {

    if ( !is_admin() && !$query->is_main_query() ) {

        if ($query->is_home()  ) {
            // Query count var
            if ( !isset($_REQUEST["BQ_EXEC"]) )
                $_REQUEST["BQ_EXEC"] = 0;

            // The block i'm interested in is no. 5
            if ( $_REQUEST["BQ_EXEC"]==5 ) {
            // Set the custom field for this case
                $query->set( 'suppress_filters', false);
                $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
                if ( empty($meta_query) )
                    $meta_query = array();
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key'=>'highlighted_in',
                    'value'=>'home'
                );
                $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
            }
            $_REQUEST["BQ_EXEC"]++;
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','my_post_filter');
```

**My question is: How can I link the call to the moment when the block is going to be executed?** How can I put a hook when the block is going to consult the data? Because if the structure of the page changes, my solution would no longer be valid.

I have little experience in the world of Wordpress, so any other way of doing this you recommend is welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: How is the original block of posts created? Are you using `WP_Query` in your template? If so, just add your meta query to that.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. the ```$query``` is a ```WP_Query``` object. I put the code in the theme/functions.php

Comment: You're trying to change the output of a feed of posts by adding your meta query, but where is that original feed coming from?

Comment: They are for the blocks: 'Post Grid' of 'Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg' plugin,  and list of items of Gutenberg editor. I wanted to modify those plugins (adding a new input text to them), but finally I thought it was not a good idea.

Comment: In that case the solution would be dependent on how that plugin implements its query. It’s something you will need to ask the plugin developer, as 3rd party plugins are off topic here. There are generic solutions to this problem when using your own code for a block/template/query, but any solution in this case will be specific to that plugin.

Comment: I can use other methods than using those plugins if you recommend a solution.